# For Loop Not Working As Expected When Manipulating Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an array of objects that I am editing.

This array varies on user selection, but generally looks like this:

`[{boxID:0,name:"Apple Bread",weight:2}]`

This array is declared as `$scope.boxes`

At a high level, this array is derived from a previously called function, the point of which is to pack items (such as Apple Bread) into boxes by weight, with no box exceeding a total weight of (in this case) 6 pounds. This array is thus filled with objects which represent the item, its weight, and the boxID (0 being the first box) that it is packed into.

My problem is, I am inserting in functionality to have the user edit the box, so that they can shuffle things around and customize their box, while still respecting the total weight limit.

To than end I have a function that utilizes drag-and-drop functionality to let the users edit and move items around their boxes. Once they are done, I need to validate what item belongs where. But I can't even get the `ondragstart` function to work properly. The idea is `ondragstart` to remove the item in question from the array, and then recalculate all the boxes, through the following:

```
$scope.boxyboxybox2 = function() {
   $scope.displayBoxes = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.boxes.length; i++) {
     if (i == 0) {
       $scope.displayBoxes.push({
         box: $scope.boxes[i].boxID,
         contents: [{
           name: $scope.boxes[i].name,
           weight: $scope.boxes[i].weight
         }]
       });
       console.log($scope.displayBoxes);
       continue;
     }
     for (var z = 0; z < $scope.displayBoxes.length; z++) {
       if ($scope.boxes[i].boxID == $scope.displayBoxes[z].box) {
         $scope.displayBoxes[z].contents.push({
           name: $scope.boxes[i].name,
           weight: $scope.boxes[i].weight
         })
         console.log($scope.boxes[i].boxID, $scope.displayBoxes[z].box, $scope.displayBoxes);
       } else {
         $scope.displayBoxes.push({
           box: $scope.boxes[i].boxID,
           contents: [{
             name: $scope.boxes[i].name,
             weight: $scope.boxes[i].weight
           }]
         });
         console.log($scope.displayBoxes);
         break;
       }
     }
   }
   console.log($scope.displayBoxes);
 }
```

The above doesn't work, I'm not utilizing `breaks` or something properly, because variations of this either get an infinite loop or I have an array of objects (in `displayBoxes` which is what goes back to the DOM) where I have duplicates, as in I have multiple instances of Box 3, for no apparent reason.

Having a hard time figuring this out. I can make a plunker if necessary but I'm hoping its just a small oversight that is apparent here, as I am quite close to my intended result.

**Edit: Plunker as requested: https://plnkr.co/edit/Bq6rgeOx26QTTu8d7AXh?p=preview**

Comment: A plunker would definitely help so people can set breakpoints to see what is going on. Also hard to debug without the ui and seeing what is happening there. Would also help to use proper indent formatting to make your code more readable

Comment: the break stops the for z loop, is that what you expect?

Comment: @charlietfl Added a plunker, sorry about code formatting will change that as well.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, that is what I expect the break to do but I think it is incorrect in that it resets the z loop too early. I'm not sure how else to do it. Please see the plunker if unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to hard code `z` as less than the length of the `displayBoxes` array.

```
for (var z = $scope.displayBoxes.length-1; z < $scope.displayBoxes.length; z++) {
```

This allowed the `break;` to be effective while maintaining the desired functionality.